# How to retrieve and bind data to ListBox from SQLCe Db

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have inserted the data into the SqlCe Database with the below code:

```
using (DBContacts context = new DBContacts(ConnectionString))
            {
                TblContacts tblCtc = new TblContacts();

                tblCtc.FirstName = txtBoxFirstNm.Text;
                tblCtc.LastName = txtBoxLastNm.Text;
                tblCtc.Mobile1 = txtMobile1.Text;
                tblCtc.Email1 = txtEmail1.Text;

                context.TblContacts.InsertOnSubmit(tblCtc);
                context.SubmitChanges();

                MessageBox.Show("Inserted Ok.");


            }
```

Questions:

1) How do I use select from Linq To SQL and display the retrieved data ?

```
 using (DBContacts context = new DBContacts(ConnectionString))
            {
              IEnumerable  ctc = from c in context.TblContacts select c;   


        // what to get the result and display ??

               // txtBlkFirstname.Text =   ctc.FirstName  ??
               // txtBlkLastname.Text = ctc.LastName    ??
               .....     

            }
```

1a) Which to use ? IQueryable or IEnumerable?

1b) What does Select-statement return?  How to handle the data-return?

1c) How to get the data out from Iqueryable or IEnumerable and assign values to the TextBlock controls?

------ How to bind the data to the ListBox

Comment: HI there, can i get a bit of more of code so that i can help you

Comment: Woukd appreciate if you can tell me which part I missed out. I got stuck on the second part : retrieving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<TblContacts> GetAllContact()
    {
        using (DBContacts context = new DBContacts(ConnectionString))
        var contacts = from m in context.TblContacts select m;
        return contacts.Take(100).ToList();
    }
```

Something similar I use in my WCF Service, should work in your app too I hope,

Try to bind a listbox source to the GetAllContacts() and then inside that listbox bind their data to the individual fields

```
       <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel Name="contentP" Opacity="1">
            <ListBox Height="623" Margin="-20,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="473">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="75" Width="75" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15,10,10,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Width="380">
                                <ContentControl Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding Title}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" TargetName="_blank"/>
                             </ContentControl>
                             <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>           
    </Grid>
```

in your code you would set the "listbox1" ItemsSource to the source of your DBQuery, not sure how you would do it in your case as I do it using my WCF Service but its something liek this

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = (result of your query ("e.Result;");
```

Comment: can you show me how to bind the Data to the ListBox with a TextBlock inside? Like <listBox> <dataTemplate> <textBlock>....</Listbox>  what to include for binding in textBlock?Thanks